# Create polygon from geo points BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, geo

I would like to create a polygon from geo points in big query.
However, I have a set of geo points which include **internal** points.

Is there a function to achieve this?

I've tried

```
ST_MAKEPOLYGON(geography_expression, array_of_geography)
```

but it expects only the polygon ring.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should generate array out of your points and create line off of that array and finally you can generate polygon from that line - see example below

```
ST_MAKEPOLYGON(ST_MAKELINE(ARRAY_AGG(geo_point)))
```

Comment: I ran this code for a list of geopoints and this is the error that I got ST_MakePolygon failed: Input geographies for STMakePolygon must be empty or consist of exactly one linestring.

Comment: Which means that you have different use case from one that is in this post. Post your question as new one and I or someone else will help you. And consider revoking your downvote for the reason I just described